# AMD Radeon Graphics Card not showing series

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

So I recently bought a Windows 11,Hp lap with a processor named,

"AMD Athlon Silver 3050U with Radeon Graphics"

When I tried to see what's my Graphics card, it said this

Name: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics

Manufacturer:Advanced Micro Devices,Inc.

Chip Type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor(0×15D8)

DAC Type:Internal DAC (400MHz)

Device Type:Full Display

So as you can see there is no specification in My Graphics card, just this. I want to know what my series Type like,

Rx6000 or HD 6550m.

Plz help me

Comment: It seems that that's just it - "Radeon Graphics" https://www.amd.com/en/product/9056

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Run Device Manager
- Open "Display adapters" and you should see the adapter
- If this is not enough, right-click it and select Properties
- Position to the Details tab
- In the drop-down list select "Hardware IDs". It will look like
  "PCI\VEN_**10DE**&DEV_**1B80**&CC_0300"
- Note down the Vendor id (after VEN_) and Device id (after DEV_) - stop at `&`
- Go to the site [PCI Lookup](https://www.pcilookup.com/)
- Enter the vendor and device ids and click "Submit".
  This will identify the device.